Pad holes are filled in Autodesk Fusion

Whenever I tried to export my PCB into pdf or using CAM, the vias are being filled. I already tried resetting my DRC, but nothing changed. I sent the fusion file to fellow classmates, and when they export it, the vias are not filled.

What do you mean by filled, just that the holes are shown in solid black?

Yes, I do not need it to be filled as solid black since I would print it with black and white colors. Isnt it supposed to be empty in the vias for drillling.
